# Changed brake pads and bled the system, but brakes go mushy when engine is running

Tags: engine, ford, brakes, truck

2007 Ford F150 4x4

After changing the brake pads and front rotors, bleeding was done and the brakes felt great.

While the vehicle was still on the jack stands, I started the engine and now the breaks feel like they need more bleeding.

When I turn off the engine the brakes begin feeling good again.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Started working after a short drive.

Comment: Depending on how they were bled, maybe you just needed a couple pumps of the pedal to get the pistons back to the normal position after being retracted to put new pads on?

Comment: @cory - Put your comment as an answer. Please don't be afraid to apply your knowledge into an answer.

Comment: I think what you're seeing is the effect of the brake booster. It is supposed to feel somewhat mushy when the engine is on compared to the situation when the engine is off.

Answer (score -1):

Check the back brakes first  if the back brakes are worn down to low it will cause your pedal to be soft . then the booster . Whenever you change your brakes all you have to do is take off your brake fluid cap take a C clamp and push the brake cylinder all the way back slowly that will force any the. Fluid back into the bowl and you will not have to bleed your breaks. Once you have installed it all back together but the tire... do not turn the engine on slowly pressure brakes real slow to the floor. When your brake pedal feels hard to the same to the next break.... Remember anytime you do front brakes you must check your back brakes..

Comment: Welcome to the site. We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution.